# Zero-One Optimization

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity

I have looked through some resources with varying success. Perhaps someone can provide a place to start. Suppose we have a finite set of real numbers, $A$, and a partition,

$A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$

such that $\forall i\in\{1,...,n\}: |A_i|\ge k$ where $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose there is a cost function, $c:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$, such that,

$c(S)=\displaystyle\sum_{s\in S}s$

for some set $S\subset \mathbb{R}$. Our task is to construct a subset, $B\subset A$, such that the following conditions hold:

1. $B$ contains exactly $k$ elements from each partition set, $A_i:i=\{1,...,n\}$.
2. $c(B)\le c*$ where $c*\in\mathbb{R}^+$.
3. $c(B)$ is maximal.

Preliminary thoughts: my first thought was to consider vectors of zeros and ones corresponding to elements of $2^A$. Then restrict this set to those satisfying the partition condition. Clearly from here we can use brute force but the numbers are massive for small sets. There must be a better way - I am ignorant to much of computational and optimization theory.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m$ be an instance of the NP-complete [PARTITION](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem. We will construct an instance of the optimization problem proposed here (converted to a decision problem) that encodes PARTITION.

Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{2m}\}$. We take $n=1$ so that there is only a single partition of $A$ consisting of $A$ itself. Let $c(a_i) = x_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,m$ and $c(a_i) = 0$ for $i=m+1, m+2, \ldots, 2m$. Finally, take $c* = 1/2\sum_{i=1}^m x_i$ and $k = m$. We leave to the reader to observe that a solution $B$ to this problem that achieves $c(B) = \lfloor c* \rfloor$ exists iff the original PARTITION problem has a solution.

While this demonstrates that a polynomial-time algorithm to obtain an exact solution to this problem in general will be unlikely, this does not rule out the possibility of heuristic approaches for approximate solutions or even exact solutions for the specific instances that you may have in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your input - would you happen to know of such heuristic approaches?

Comment: I am aware of some heuristic approaches to the basic PARTITION problem but those may or may not be applicable to your situation. For example, if $n$ (the number of $A_i$) is large, then I suspect that your problem's characteristics diverge significantly from PARTITION. The effectiveness of heuristic approaches may be dependent on the precise parameters of your problem instances (e.g.: the number of $A_i$, the range of $c$, etc...).

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a good starting point to move forward. I thought the question I was asking may be quite accessible given a bit of relevant background - never assume I suppose lol